# The Prisma package exits in package.json but I can not see related files also not in the plugins list when i entered `godspeed plugin add` command?

Tags: plugins, prisma

I've created a sample project with Godspeed, but when I attempt to run it, I encounter an error indicating that the Prisma file cannot be found. Although the package.json is present, there are no corresponding TypeScript files. How can I address this error and install the Prisma plugin?

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter a Prisma error despite having `@godspeedsystems/plugins-express-as-http` installed, try resolving the issue by removing the plugin from package.json. Afterward, add it again using the godspeed plugin add command.